# I can't extract items in a loop correctly. I extract only the last single number and not the whole list

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, loops, dictionary

If i write `HockeyMatch[row[0]].append(row[3])` i correctly get the list of hockey matches with their last points won, for example `Chicago-Minnesota [4, 2, 0, 3]`, because `row[0]` is the name of the hockey game and `row[3]` is the list of last games points won by Chicago.

My goal is to also add the tournament `name` (it's `row[1]`) and `date` (it's `row[2]`) to it, so I get this:

```
{('Chicago-Minnesota', 'NHL', 12/27/ 2022): [4, 2, 0, 3]
```

I tried to do this, writing like this:

```
HockeyMatch[ row[0],row[1],row[2] ].append(row[3])
```

The problem though is i get this `Chicago-Minnesota, NHL, 27.12.2022, [4]`. As you can see, `[4]` is the last point conquered in the list [4, 2, 0, 3].

Instead if I try to write `HockeyMatch[row[0]].append(row[3])`, I get correctly `[4, 2, 0, 3]`, but obviously without date and tournament, so `Chicago-Minnesota [4, 2, 0, 3]`

How can I correctly print the list of games with `date` (is `row[2]`), `tournament` (is `row[1]`) and last `points` won (is `row[3]`)? I would like to get this `{('Chicago-Minnesota', 'NHL', 12/27/2022): [4, 2, 0, 3]` (and other hockey matchs)

```
HockeyMatch = {}

conn_test = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
cursor_test = conn_test.cursor()
my = cursor_test.execute('''SELECT Next.ClubHome||"-"||Next.ClubAway, Next.Tournament, Next.Date, MatchResults.ScoreHome
                                    FROM Next
                                    INNER JOIN MatchResults 
                                    ON Next.ClubHome = MatchResults.ClubHome;''') 

for row in my.fetchall():
    if row[0] not in HockeyMatch:

        HockeyMatch[ row[0],row[1],row[2] ] = []
    HockeyMatch[ row[0],row[1],row[2] ].append(row[3])
    print(HockeyMatch)
```

Example database

NEXT

```
| ClubHome | ClubAway   | Tournament | Date |
---------------------------------------------
| Chicago  | Minnesota  | NHL        | 27.12|
| Arizona  | Los Angeles| NHL        | 27.12|
| Dallas   | Vegas Gold | NHL        | 27.12|
```

MATCHRESULTS

To connect to the example in the question, here I only select Chicago who are in ClubHome and select their points. I'm not interested in ClubAway

```
| ClubHome | ClubAway   | Tournament | Date | ScoreHome | ScoreAway
--------------------------------------------------------------------
| Chicago  | Toronto    | NHL        | 27.12| 1         | 2 
| New York | Vegas Gold | NHL        | 27.12| 2         | 3
| Dallas   | Minnesota  | NHL        | 27.12| 0         | 1
| Chicago  | Buffalo Sab| NHL        | 27.12| 2         | 0
```

and other matchs...

Comment: The tournaments or dates must be different, so you get a different key.

Comment: Post the non-working code, not the working code.

Comment: Your code should work if `row[0], row[1], row[2]` are the same in 2 different rows. Otherwise, it doesn't make sense to combine the scores.

Comment: @Barmar The comma was just an oversight in writing the code here. The broken code I posted with a comment next to my code. It's just two lines. Can you help me please? Do you know how I can fix the problem?

Comment: As I said, it should work the way you wrote it. Are you sure you have multiple results with the same `row[0], row[1], row[2]`? Show some sample data.

Comment: @Barmar row[0] and row[1] are equal in 2 different rows. row[3] no, because it is present only in the Next table.

Comment: What about `row[2]`, the date?

Comment: @Barmar Yes, row[2] is the date. I explained it above. row[0] is the match, row[1] is the tournament, row[3] are the scores. Ok, now I'll show you some sample data. Give me a few minutes of time

Comment: I know what they are. But you can't get multiple values in the same dictionary element if part of the key is different, and the dates must be different.

Comment: @Barmar Here is an example of data. I made a collage in one image: https://ibb.co/pJ6M4p8 However I checked, row[0], row[1], row[2] are the same on 2 different rows. In both tables of the database, in addition to the match, there is also the date and tournament. How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Your query uses `Next.team_home`, is that supposed to be `Next.ClubHome`? Why are there so many mistakes in the posted code, can't you just copy and paste the actual code?

Comment: Your query doesn't make sense. It will join results that have a different `ClubAway` than `Next`. It should be `ON Next.ClubHome = MatchResults.ClubHome AND Next.ClubAway = MatchResults.ClubAway`

Comment: @Barmar It is Next.ClubHome. I wrote the code, simplifying it for stackoverflow. It was an oversight, but that's not the problem. Now I correct the question. But that's not the problem. Thanks for pointing it out to me. Do you have any idea how I can get the solution asked in the question? Thank you

Comment: Please post your data as text in the question. I can't import from n image.

Comment: @Barmar If you don't understand, don't say it doesn't make sense please. I find it a bit offensive. I get exactly what I want (without date and tournament). For basically every ClubHome in Next, I want to get the points earned by ClubHome in previous matches in MatchResults where the club name is in ClubHome and not in ClubAway. I'm not interested in ClubAway. Ok, now I post my data as text

Comment: SOrry about that. Please post sample data and expected results, it's hard to tell what you expect and what you're getting instead.

Comment: @Barmar Don't worry. I've updated my question with some data. I hope you can help me. If you don't understand something, just ask me. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
    if row[0] not in HockeyMatch:
```

to

```
    if (row[0], row[1],row[2]) not in HockeyMatch:
```

When you change the key to a tuple, you have to search for the tuple with `in`.

You can simplify this by using `collections.defaultdict()` or `dict.setdefault()`.

```
for row in data:
    HockeyMatch.setdefault((row[0],row[1],row[2]), []).append(row[3])
    print(HockeyMatch)
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. Answer accepted of course. I would also like to vote for you but I don't have the necessary minimum score

Comment: Accepting the answer gives more reputation than an upvote.